# How to block specific email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) and I need to prevent that some spam addresses stop sending recurrent leads.

Tried Google and reading the plugin documentation, but I'm a beginner in JS, so I couldn't find anything I needed.

P.S. Not talking about invalid email addresses but recurrent valid email addresses.

Comment: the only way to check if an email is valid is to send something to it and then make the user open the email and get that out.  It is a horrible user experience , but most sites do it because it is the only way

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". In other words, at least try and write some code.

Comment: Also, please search SO before posting.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I searched through google, github foruns and SO but didn't find exactly what I was lookig for, **as I said, I'm a beginner**.

Comment: @Sparky First read the coment above. Anyway, thelinks attached probably will help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please keep in mind that you should **always double check user input serverside**. Malicious users will always be able to bypass rules that are set clientside. Also, **by doing it in JavaScript, you are disclosing your list of banned emails**, and making it easier for hackers to see what they should do to bypass your rules.

That being said, you can load [jQuery Validate's *Additional methods* plugin](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js) and use [addMethod](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to create your own rules:

```js
// Banning domains
var bannedDomains = ["spam.com", "junk.com"];

$.validator.addMethod('domainNotBanned', function(value, elem, param) {
  var domain = value.split('@')[1];
  return bannedDomains.indexOf(domain) < 0;
}, 'Emails from this domain are not allowed.');

// Banning specific addresses
var bannedEmails = ["mean@hacker.com", "kim.kardashian@gmail.com"];

$.validator.addMethod('emailNotBanned', function(value, elem, param) {
  return bannedEmails.indexOf(value) < 0;
}, 'This email address is banned.');

// Applying these rules
$('#myForm').validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      domainNotBanned: true,
      emailNotBanned: true
    }
  }
});

// Just for the demo
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("This email is valid.");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="#" method="POST">                                                                                                                                                                                                                     <style>#email-error { display: block; color: red; }</style>
  <label for="email">Email: </label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" minlength="6"/><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a table in your DB to save the emails and domains that you don't want and check them before to do the next step.